# Access friend class's private member

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list, nested-class

I'm trying to write a console application like Twitter. User and UserList classes including each other. I'm trying to access to following user's followers. UserList class is used for linked list.

```
//User.h

#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class UserList;
class User
{
   friend class UserList;
private:
   string userName;
   string personalComment;
   UserList *followed;
   UserList *following;
   int followedNumber;
   int followingNumber;
   //TWEET
   UserList *blocked;
   User* next;
public:
   User();
   User(string&,string&);
};

//UserList.h
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class User;

class UserList{
private:
    User *root;
public:
    UserList();
    ~UserList();
    void addUser(string&,string&);
    bool checkUser(string&);
    User& findUser(string&);
    void printList();
};
```

Firstly, I wrote a function to find following user.

```
//userList.cpp
User& UserList::findUser(string& name)
{
   User *temp=root;
   while(temp!=NULL)
   {
       if(!name.compare(temp->userName))
       {
            return temp;
       }
       temp= temp->next;
    }
    temp= temp->next;
    return temp;
}
```

For example user1 wants to follow user2. I want to check does user1 already follow user2.( checkUser(username) looks for a user in a list and return bool)

```
//main.cpp in main()
if(users.findUser(user1name).following->checkUser(user2name))
{
            cout<<"Err: The user '"<< user1name << "' has already followed '"<<user2name<<"'!"<<endl;
}
```

But there is a "UserList* User::following is private" error and "within this context"

How can I access this user's lists?

Comment: twitter is a console application?

Comment: @tobi303 Thought the exact same thing. :P Apparently there are people not using a HTML renderer but just reading the tags and all...

Comment: There is no `User::followed` in your code

Comment: I don't see any *nested* class here, there is no class declaration or definition inside `class User`.

Comment: @MervePia Where's `UserList` nested in `User`?

Comment: You definitely do not show us the line that causes the error. Now you fixed the typo but in the code you show you are never trying to acces `User::followed`

Comment: well I thought you fixed the typo, but you didnt ....

Comment: BTW, you could use `if (name == temp->userName)` instead of using the `compare` method; less typing.

Comment: Lets assume the error is `User::following` is private. Then it is still hard to tell how to fix without knowing where the last code snippet is placed. In main?

Comment: Posting `UserList` declaration would help.

Comment: I corrected "follower" as a "followed".But I think this is not the problem. errors coming from if line

Comment: "within this context" which context? Where is this if line?

Comment: tobi303  error line:  if(users.findUser(user1name).following->checkUser(user2name))

Comment: and this line is where in your code?

Comment: @MervePia That's a train-wreck, post a [MCVE] please. Otherwise it's not possible to diagnose your problems.

Comment: sorry, I must have missed the line "//main.cpp in main()". Shouldnt `checkUser(username)` be a method of `UserList`?

Comment: First, I try to find user1,then I try to look user1's following list for user2. Is findUser returning type wrong? Or is if statements condition wrong?

Comment: Argh forget my last comment... The point is: you cannot access private members outside of the class. Expection: You can access them inside a class that is declared as friend. But you cannot access it in the main.

Comment: checkUser() is in UserList. I added UserList.h to my question

Comment: The code with the error should be encapsulated in the `UserList` class, this will make the error disappear.

Comment: oww, how can I encapsulate ? should I write a function which will be return UserLists in User object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you should not put logic of your classes in the `main`. Your issue can be solved for example by adding a method to `User` that tries to add another user instead of doing this in the `main`. Something like this:

```
User::FollowOther(std::string other){
    if(this->following->checkUser(other)) {
        cout<<"Err: The user '"<< userName << "' has already followed '"<<other<<"'!"<<endl;
    }
    /*...*/
}
```

The error you got is because `User::following` is private in `User`. Private members can only be accessed from within the class. The exception is: You can access private members from within a different class that is declared as friend. But you cannot access private members in the `main`. Btw, I am not at all a fan of declaring friends, because it breaks encapsulation and makes the relation between classes less obvious, but thats just my personal opinion.

Comment: oh I get it! I'm trying now

Comment: @MervePia there are some other smaller issues with your code, e.g. why do you store pointers to the lists? I see no need to do so. And another minor thing: having `followedNumber` and `followingNumber` as members of `User` forces you to write unnecessary code because you will have to keep this numbers up to date. Instead provide a `size()` method for `UserList` that will serve the same purpose.